# VBA Adding Vlookup + Vlookup w/ active cell

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am once again here to see if anyone is willing to hep with this question I am having.
I thank you all in advance.

[image]

Looking at the picture above, we have SHEET 1 and SHEET 2, they represent 2 different sheets that for the purpose of this explanation I have made in the same sheet, but in reality, it will be in 2 spearate sheets.

So basically I need a VBA code that when I press that Red Button, the code takes the 100 from cell C11, adds to cell I11 (mind you, I11 is in a different sheet), and then erase all content from cell C11 and E11.

Since it is only one button that will be used for several rows, I have read somewhere that you can use a thing called "active cell" to avoid creating a single button for each row.

So this is the code I though of to simply add those 2, but I do not know how to put it into VBA to run with "activesheet".

`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G11)),VLOOKUP(A11,G11:I20,3,0))+ VLOOKUP(A11,A11:E20,3,0)`

So this is what the result would be if the button worked correctly:

[image]

I would appreciate if anyone could explain to me how to incorporate activesheet together with the vlookup code up there, about the erasing cells i have used it before so i can look it up.

Thanks in advance again.

Comment: So is not a code writing service.  Please post the code you have tried with a clear description of the specific problem you are having.  Please make sure you indicate the line of code that is causing the error.  Please make sure you remove all on error statements from your code so that you get clear and correct error messages.

Comment: ah shoot, i forgot to write the vlookup code i had, lemme update it

Comment: In simpler words, do you want selecting a cell in "A:A" column first sheet and running the code it must find the correspondent row having the same "ITEM ID" in "A:A" of the second sheet. Then adding the existing value of I:I column (the found row) with C:C value of the of the active cell row (on first sheet).  After that delete values in C:E on the active cell row. Is this understanding a correct one?

Comment: exactly that yes

Comment: Then, try the code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try using the next code. You can call it from the button you already have, or copy it **As** the respective code:

```
Sub updateQuantity()
  Dim rng As Range, ws2 As Worksheet, rngItem As Range
  
  Set rng = ActiveCell
  If rng.cells.count > 1 Then MsgBox "You need to select only ONE CELL...": Exit Sub
  If rng.column <> 1 Then MsgBox "The active cell must be in A:A column...": Exit Sub
  
  Set ws2 = rng.Parent.Next ' Set the second worksheet
                            ' in this code it is the next sheet after the one keeping active cell
                            
  Set rngItem = ws2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=rng.value, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'find the Item in the second sheet
  If Not rngItem Is Nothing Then 'if the item has been found:
     'add the existing value in I:I (found range row) with the one from C:C column (activecell row)
     ws2.cells(rngItem.Row, "I").value = ws2.cells(rngItem.Row, "I").value + rng.Offset(, 2).value
     rng.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 3).ClearContents 'clear content of C:E columns of the active cell row
  Else
     MsgBox "No any match for item """ & rng.value & """ has been found in """ & _
           ws2.name & """ sheet..."
  End If
End Sub
```

If the button you have is of `ActiveX` type, write `updateQuantity` in its `Click` event. If it is a `Form` button, assig the above macro to it.

If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply! 
I have adjusted your code to fit on my real excel file (just switched around coordinates) and I am getting a runtime error 13 on the line right before "clear content" (ws2.cells(rngItem.Row, "I")......), i will keep trying to adjust it and come back to you ASAP.

Comment: @Eric Ahn I am afraid that the way you "adapted it" is not the most appropriate. What do you mean by "switched around coordinates"? What coordinates are you talking about? Don't you need changing the ranges **you mentioned in your question**? Did you adapt `Set ws2 = rng.Parent.Next` to use your real (second) sheet? Besides the error number, what is its description, please?

Comment: Sorry, the terms I used might have been unclear, I changed the ranges and the cell numbers (for example: changed "I" to "E") and used 'Set ws2 = Sheets("Material_Index")', Material_Index being the name of the sheet.

Comment: @Eric Ahn Then, do you understand the meaning of `Offset` and `Resize` properties to adapt them correctly? Besides that, why did you ask for specific ranges and now you want using the code for something else? I cannot understand this way of asking questions, no offence... Do you have AnyDesk installed? If so and nothing confidential, can I connect to your computer to see what's happening in your environment?

Comment: The purpose of the code you wrote will be used exactly for what was intended. I have to rearrange the ranges because my company will not allow me to post the actual table in a public forum for obvious reasons, so I made a similar but not so similar table. If I had no restriction to post the actual table I would have done so no problem. I guess next time I will have to be more specific regarding the table matching the cell numbers as well.
Also rather than ask for an exact code, I am more interested in learning of what concept was used to solve the problem, so I can learn from it

Comment: @Eric Ahn Did you try testing the code **as it is**, on your almost similar situation? Only copying the range starting from column G:G to I:I in the next/following sheet... I tested the code before posting it and it works as it should. Only after testing it in the way you required and understanding its functionality, it would be good to try adapting, I would say...

Comment: You are right, it works beautifully when in its original form, it will help me adapt it to my table, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Eric Ahn Doesn't it work beautifully, anymore? Is it something to be improved/adapted?

Comment: I have managed to adapt it, I realized that I was putting the wrong number for offset so the macro was not being able to add the 2 cells together.

Comment: @Eric Ahn And do you consider that what you try explaining now was a good reason to un-accept the answer, if it worked **as it was**, answering your question **as it was formulated**?

Comment: I did not realize I had un-accepted the answer. I just re-accepted the answer, sorry for any confusion this might have caused. Edit: seriously, this is weird, If i DID unaccept it, it was not done intentionally, I do not recall unaccepting the answer.

Comment: @Eric Ahn I do not care too much about reputation score. I have enough, on my taste. I was notified about the un-acceptance and I just wanted to understand what was happening...

Comment: yea, i have no doubt your rep score must be high, but yea, i dont know when i cancelled it or even how i cancelled it, i think i must have mistakenly missclicked on the check mark idk, anyways, thanks again for the help, i am using your code and has already helped me a lot.